# Multilanguage chrome extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, internationalization

I am currently writing a chrome extension which has quite a lot of text on its options page. I want to offer the content in multiple languages.

I read the api about i18n, but that mainly covers Js-Functionality.

How to display different languages in my html files? The following three options come into my mind:
1. Display every text by using jQuery to manipulate the dom. Seems a bit bad for the readibality of the source.
2. Use the "lang" - tag for divs etc. Do these work in chrome extensions and is the language correctly offered to the page?
3. Different html-files for each language. Can the selection of the right page done by vars in the manifest?
4. Something completely different.
How to solve that dilemma?

Comment: You could template it all out and generate the html depending on the i18n context

Comment: I kinda "solved" this by putting a "currentlanguage" parameter inside the _locale-folder and redirecting the options-page depending on that value